# append object if not exist swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, function, append

Im new to swift language and I'm trying to find a solution for my problem.
I have created a class called Book

I am tring to create Book. A book has name (can’t be changed after creation), purchaseid (can’t be changed after creation), and market price (can be changed)

and also a class Shelf. A shelf has name (that can’t be changed after creation) and an array of books (that can be changed by calling add and delete methods and is unique on book purchaseId - ie. doesn’t have duplicate purchaseIds). Shelf also has a method for computing the average price of books in the shelf.

I am trying to find a solution on how to check an array before adding to it and taking books purchaseId and deleting a book from the array.

here is my code:

```
class Book{
    let name: String
    let purchaseID: Int
    let marketPrice: Double




    init(name: String, purchaseID: Int, marketPrice: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.purchaseID = purchaseID
        self.marketPrice = marketPrice
    }


    func bookPrinter() -> String {
        return "Name: \(self.name) Price: \(marketPrice)"

    }

}

class Shelf{
    private let shelfName: String
    private var arrayOfBooks = [Book]()


    init(shelfName: String) {
        self.shelfName = shelfName
    }

    func add(book : Book ){
   
    
    }

   
    func delete(book : Book){

    }


    func printer() {
        for b in self.arrayOfBooks{
            print(b.bookPrinter())
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean that `purchaseId` uniquely identifies a Book?

Comment: If the order of the books on the shelf doesn't matter you should use a `Set`

Comment: Yes, I mean that purchaseId uniquely identifies a Book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `add(book:)` function, if the book's `purchaseID` is unique, you can use `contains(where:)` function to know if the `Book` already exists in the Array:

```
func add(book: Book){
    if !arrayOfBooks.contains(where: { $0.purchaseID == book.purchaseID }) {
        arrayOfBooks.append(book)
    }
}
```

or add an extension to `Book` that conforms to `Equatable` protocol:

```
extension Book: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Book, rhs: Book) -> Bool {
        return lhs.purchaseID == rhs.purchaseID
    }
}
```

and simplify your `add(book:)` function:

```
func add(book: Book){
    if !arrayOfBooks.contains(book) {
        arrayOfBooks.append(book)
    }
}
```

For `delete(book:)` function you can use `removeAll(where:)` function of Array:

```
func delete(book: Book){
    arrayOfBooks.removeAll(where: { $0.purchaseID == book.purchaseID })
}
```

However, as @LeoDabus said in the comments, if book ordering doesn't mater you should probably use a `Set`. It will be faster on some aspects.

An implementation may be like this:

```
extension Book: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Book, rhs: Book) -> Bool {
        return lhs.purchaseID == rhs.purchaseID
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(purchaseID)
    }
}

class Shelf {
    private let shelfName: String
    private var setOfBooks = Set<Book>()

    init(shelfName: String) {
        self.shelfName = shelfName
    }

    func add(book: Book){
        setOfBooks.insert(book)
    }

    func delete(book: Book){
        setOfBooks.remove(book)
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. Thank  you for your quick response.